# Model Schema support in Azure API Management

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle, azure-api-management

In the Swagger UI, the model/model schema are documented in the Parameters section. When I import the same documentation into the Azure API Management portal, parameters with .NET data types are documented but the complex object/model/model schema in the request body loses its documentation.

I saw an update for Model Schema support [Azure API Management adds support for Swagger model schemas](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-api-management-adds-support-for-swagger-model-schemas/).

But it did not work when I tried it in the API Portal.

1. Do anyone know how to import the Model Schema Documentation into the Azure API Management Portal?
2. Is this update available in New Portal only? And if so when will API management be available in New Portal?

Note: I am using Swagger 2.0 documentation from Swashbuckle in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Model schemas are imported if they are in the Swagger file. If that's not the case your saw, can you please send your Swagger file to apimgmt at microsoft dotcom so that we can take a look at the file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repro this issue and have fixed it.  Hopefully, I will be able to get the fix in the next release.

Comment: Could you give us an update about when to expect the next release? We're desparately waiting for this update

Comment: @standardModel Testing the release build right now, it should start rolling out next week.